# Can't match the `java -version` using expr command

Tags: bash

I am using bash shell and expr command.Below is my scripts:

```
v=`java -version`

echo 'check java platform...'

echo `expr match "$v" 'java'`
```

Can't match java substring, just got 0.
But if I use this : v='java version "1.6.0_34"' 
I got the correct result:4

Why? How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
export v=`java -version 2>&1`
echo $v
```

Comment: Thanks. Could explain a bit, any document?

Comment: I tried v=\`java -version\` and v has nothing, then it must be in stderr.